# Adding a grid on canvas bring some lag, optimisations?

Tags: javascript, canvas

That's the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mgq79/3/

```
  for (var xgrid = 0; xgrid < (canvasWidth / grid_step); xgrid++)
  {
    ctx.moveTo(xgrid * grid_step, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(xgrid * grid_step, canvasHeight);
  }
  for (var ygrid = 0; ygrid < (canvasHeight / grid_step); ygrid++)
  {
    ctx.moveTo(0, ygrid * grid_step);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasWidth, ygrid * grid_step);
  }
```

Long story short - after adding the grid, noticed some lag while rendering at small velocity values (<=150m/s) while it was almost smooth near upper 1000m/s limit. So how to optimise this part?

Thanks

ps link updated
Also note that lag is very noticeable when trajectories are 3 or more

Comment: Your fiddle does not appear to work at all. You have to include the code in the `HEAD` of the document, not call it at the DOM ready event: http://jsfiddle.net/Mgq79/3/.

Comment: That's a problem of jsfiddle, not mine. Works on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yes, because you didn't set up the fiddle correctly. If you include a demo, make sure that it works, otherwise, what's the point? Not everyone wants to spend time to fix your demo to be able to help you at all. I linked to a working version in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works about the same. It's only 1 ms difference which I'm sure you can't really notice.

I for one would really want to skip drawing that grid over and over and I would make the canvas transparent and have the grid as a repeating background image of the canvas container.

Or draw it once on a temp canvas and then use drawimage and just move it over to your canvas if redrawing it is necessary for some reason.

Also, you should use a path to draw the graph and not 1x1 rectangles. The path can be finished after all the points are there. Drawing and filling a rectangle at every iteration is bound to be slow.

Comment: What should I do to use temp canvas? Also using `ctx.strokeRect(xgrid * grid_step, 0, grid_step, canvasHeight);` and `ctx.strokeRect(0, ygrid * grid_step, canvasWidth, grid_step);` to generate grid seems more laggy.

Comment: create a canvas object (or have another hidden one in the html), draw the grid on it once at initialization then just take its content and draw it on your visible one when you need.

Comment: Overlaying two `canvas` elements and only redrawing the one with the trajectories would be a solution as well.